# Random.choices not returning uniform distribution

Tags: python, random, statistics

I am trying to simulate a uniform distribution of discrete values using random.choices. Each time that a new set is generated, a key representing the unique counts is incremented.

Why is the uniform outcome `([2,2])` less likely to occur than `[1,3]`?

```
def sim_counts(size, values=[1,-1], popsize=2):
    
    count_dict = {}
    for i in range(popsize):
        X = random.choices(values,k=size)
        _, counts = np.unique(X, return_counts=True)
        
        if len(counts) == 1:
            counts = [0,counts[0]]
        key = str(np.sort(counts))

        if key not in count_dict:
            count_dict[key] = 0
            count_dict[key] +=1
        else:
            count_dict[key] +=1
            
    return count_dict
   
sim_counts(4, values=[1,-1], popsize=10000)

>>> {'[2 2]': 3747, '[0 4]': 1319, '[1 3]': 4934}
```

Comment: set `key = str(counts)` rather than `key = str(numpy.sort(counts))` and you will see why :-)

Comment: Oh gosh! Thanks

Comment: Also, this code would be a lot cleaner if you did "from collections import defaultdict" and then set count_dict = defaultdict(int).  Then you could just do count_dict[key] += 1 without the if/else statement.

Comment: @JonSG, if you write that as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: @user2263572 or just use `Counter` while you are at it

Comment: You can also randomy generate like this: `return {f"[{k} {4-k}]": v for k, v in zip(*np.unique((np.random.randint(0, len(values), size=(4, popsize))).sum(axis=0), return_counts=True))}` which should be very close to `return {f"[{k} {4-k}]": v for k, v in zip(*np.unique(np.random.binomial(4, 0.5, size=popsize), return_counts=True))}`

Comment: Thanks Whole Brain, very elegant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As part of the tidy of the code, you are setting `key = str(numpy.sort(counts))` and this is hiding that there are two ways to get a key of `[1 3]` using that strategy.

If you run the test again without the sort, I think you will find that the result `[2 2]` is more common as you expected but that the results of `[1 3]` and `[3 1]` while individually less combine to a greater amount.

For example:

```
{'[3 1]': 2521, '[1 3]': 2550, '[2 2]': 3721, '[0, 4]': 1208}
```

Please also see @barmar's answer for a more nuanced look at the individual permutations that result in the keys in question.

Comment: Thanks. I made a rookie mistake.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually more of a mathematical question than programming.

Here are all the permutations that produce `[3 1]` counts:

```
[1, 1, 1, -1]
[1, 1, -1, 1]
[1, -1, 1, 1]
[-1, 1, 1, 1]
[-1, -1, -1, 1]
[-1, -1, 1, -1]
[-1, 1, -1, -1]
[1, -1, -1, -1]
```

Here are all the `[2 2]` permutations:

```
[1, 1, -1, -1]
[1, -1, 1, -1]
[-1, 1, 1, -1]
[1, -1, -1, 1]
[-1, 1, -1, 1]
[-1, -1, 1, 1]
```

So the ratio is 8:6, which is the approximate ratio of your results.